# tensorflow predict gives same values for any input

Tags: classification, keras, tensorflow, image-classification

I'm trying to create a classification model for images, using TensorFlow and Keras.

For this classification problem, I've created a model like this:

```
Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
BatchNormalization(),
MaxPooling2D(),
Dropout(0.5),
BatchNormalization(), # as of my knowledge this is wrong, we should use bnorm after activation layers, right?
Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu'),
BatchNormalization(),
MaxPooling2D(),
Dropout(0.5),
BatchNormalization(),
Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu'),
BatchNormalization(),
MaxPooling2D(),
Dropout(0.5),
Flatten(),
Dense(128, activation='relu'),
BatchNormalization(),
Dense(len(classes))
```

And the model is compiled like this:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The problem is the model train with an accuracy of 97% and validation accuracy of 84%.

**But when I test the model, for any output I just get one constant output.**

Here is my whole notebook: https://www.kaggle.com/code/maifeeulasad/paddy-doctor-paddy-disease-classification

*This is an ongoing Kaggle competition without any prizes of my knowledge*

Comment: You missed the activation of the last layer. Hence you are not classifying.

Comment: @Oscar if you please take a look at the notebook, I've already done so... but it is still the same: https://www.kaggle.com/code/maifeeulasad?scriptVersionId=93450691&cellId=6